# Input value two-way data binding not updating with empty string

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8

I'm using Angular 8.1.3. Here's my HTML...

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
  <input matInput placeholder="Address Line 2" [value]="addressLine2" [disabled]="disableAddressFields">
</mat-form-field>
```

I have the following in my TypeScript file.

```
addressLine2 = '';
```

Changing to a non-empty string **is reflected** in the HTML.

```
this.addressLine2 = 'some value';
```

But setting it back to an empty string does **is not reflected** in the HTML, despite the value being empty ('') in the TypeScript (confirmed by printing to console).

```
this.addressLine2 = '';
```

It seems that once a non-empty string is set in the TypeScript, an empty string that is set is not reflected in the HTML. I'm kind of lost here; any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two way binding to work you need to use `[(ngModel)]`. Import angular forms add add `[(ngModel)]` to your code.

```
 <input matInput placeholder="Address Line 2" [(ngModel)]="addressLine2" [disabled]="disableAddressFields">
```

In your current code you are binding `input`'s value property to `addressLine2` so it is working as expected. To also get data back from input field you need to use `ngModel`

```
  <input matInput placeholder="Address Line 2" [value]="addressLine2" [disabled]="disableAddressFields">
```

Comment: Ah, that fixes it! Thank you for the detailed answer. :)

Comment: @alt255 - Why do you say "In your current code you are binding input's `value` property to `disableAddressFields`"?

Comment: @ConnorsFan it was a typo . fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [value]="addressline2", it should be [(ngmodel)]="addressline2" for two way binding

Comment: Not if the OP is using forms. Using `[(ngModel)]` within `ngForm` was removed in v7.